# installing appcelerator app on android 4.0.4 device

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium

i am getting issue with installing appcelerator app on android 4.0.4 device

it throws following error while installing app on device:

> **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Activity.startActivity; Titanium 5.2.0**

i just created simple window in my application.

code snippets:

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor:'red'
});
window.open();
```

however if i implement `tabgroup` and open it then it working fine.

could anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20564) for this issue. There is also a PR to fix the issue as well. I would guess that this fix would be included in the next release. You could download a nightly build or integrate the fix into a custom SDK build if you need it before then.